# What code to place in a post to have exactly these three social media buttons looking like this?

Tags: language-agnostic

Look below the title
http://news.cnet.com/8301-30684_3-20010696-265.html

retweet, fbshare count and digg.

What code (html, css, js) is needed to place in a html to have them looking exactly like that? :)

Answer (score 1):

A little bit of googling often helps:

- http://help.tweetmeme.com/2009/04/06/tweetmeme-button/
- http://www.fbshare.me/
- http://about.digg.com/button

Comment: It never looks exactly aligned like this